# substitute attribute zero values with average of items with similar attributes

Tags: python, pandas

I have some height data of probes in certain basins. The zero height values are spurious and I want to substitute them with the average height values of the probes in the same basin.

```
import pandas as pd

index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
s = pd.Series([0,2,2,0,1,6],index= index)  #height values
t = pd.Series(['A','A','A','B','B','B'],index= index)  #basins' names
df = pd.concat([s,t], axis=1, keys=['Height','Basin'])
print(df)

   Height Basin
0       0     A
1       2     A
2       2     A
3       0     B
4       1     B
5       6     B
```

I start by creating a DataFrame that stores the average heights in a basin:

```
#find height avergage in same basin
bound_df = df[df['Height']>0]
mean_height_df = bound_df.groupby(['Basin'])['Height'].mean()
print(mean_height_df)

Basin
A    2.0
B    3.5
```

And the I try to substitute the zero values with the average values of the corresponding basin:

```
#substitute zeros w/ the average value
df.loc[df['Height']<=0, 'Height'] = mean_height_df.loc[mean_height_df['Basin'],'Height']
```

But this throws an error that I do not understand:

> File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> KeyError: 'Basin'

What does this mean? Is it a slicing problem?

Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. Try using `fillna`, the values are filled based on the index. You will need a little setup, and then you can use `mean_height_df` as usual.

```
# Set "Basin" as the index.
v = df.set_index('Basin')['Height']  
# Mask values that <= 0 and fill NaNs by the computed mean. 
df['Height'] = v.mask(v.le(0)).fillna(mean_height_df).values
```

Comment: I am having some problems to adapt this solution when in the original data frames there are extra features other than `height` and `basin`. For example, if other than `s` and `t`, I also had `u = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2],index= index)` with `df = pd.concat([s,t,u], axis=1, keys=['Height','Basin','stuff'])`. Indeed, the fix you suggested would return a df with only Basin and Height. Do you know how to modify it?